# Renaming a file without copying it; any alternative to OverlayFS?

Tags: linux, rename, overlay, mount

I want to have a "virtual" filesystem like OverlayFS where I can rename the files and folders, but without copying the whole file. I have an archive with over 800TB of Data and the files need to be renamed, but I want to keep the original folder structure and the filenames.

For instance:

- I have the 800tb mount on `/mnt/archive`.
- I want an "overlay" mount on `/mnt/archive_renamed`.

So that a file, for example `Data001.bin` on `/mnt/archive` can be renamed on the overlaymount and look something like this `/mnt/archive_renamed/Data_from_2014/Data_from_Cats.bin` but belongs still to `Data001.bin` and never touches the underlying mount.

OverlayFS would be perfect if it doesn't need to copy the whole file when renaming it.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /mnt/archive_renamed, you can use hardlinks to the original files.
Just do "cp -al /mnt/archive /mnt/archive_renamed" and you'll have to folders pointing to the same files.